# How to extract a substring using regex in Goo

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a table that has the columns_text content.  
The "word_list" column is from another table and 
I would like to extract from the "columns_text" just the part that matches the word in the word_list. 
So the result will be just the word that matches the "word_list" column
Is it possible to do it on Google Sheets with formula?

| word_list | columns_text | result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Milk | AB - 01 - Specific - Dmodel - Milk | Milk |
| Apple | AB - 01 - Specific - Dmodel - Delta Milk | Milk |
| Orange | text-milk-dmodel-specific | Milk |
| Beans | dmodel_milk_specif_text | Milk |
| Rice | Text / Dmodel / MILK / SPECIFIC | Milk |
| Wine | text specific milk model | Milk |
| Water | AC - 04 - Specific - Dmodel - Apple twist | Apple |
| Juice | AB - 01 - Specific - Dmodel - The Apple | Apple |
|  | text-apple-dmodel-specific | Apple |
|  | Text / Dmodel / APPLE / SPECIFIC | Apple |

Comment: This does not really require regular expressions to be honest. Have you tried any formula?

Comment: @JvdV What about the solution provided? Isn't this regex? Also... Looking at the closing reasons I see "Needs more focus"... like what? Any thoughts?

Comment: I haven't voted to close as yet but surely this is getting closed because it indeed needs more focus. There has been no attempt made by OP which is basically a "give me a solution" type of question. It would improve in quality if an attempt at a formula or a regex pattern can be included for sure. @marikamitsos. Btw, with the sample data as is there is no need for regex I'd say (yet, you are free to deliver a solution with it offcourse).

Comment: *"There has been no attempt..."* and *"with the sample data as is..."*. First of all, sorry I thought you had one of the votes. Still. Though I would tend to agree with you we quite a few many times find "give me a solution" type of questions that we answer any way. Also. A regex may not be needed. Still. It is one of the solutions nevertheless.

Comment: @marikamitsos, consider the ones we answer the lucky ones =).

Answer (score 1):

Please try

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(LOWER(W2:W),LOWER(JOIN("|",V2:V9)))))
```

[image]

Functions used:

- [`ArrayFormula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [`IFERROR`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304)
- [`REGEXEXTRACT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244)
- [`LOWER`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094083)

Comment: it's always good to sort V2:V9 in descending order coz if V10 = watermelon regex will extract only water out of it and a dry melon is not delicious at all